# Setting class properties quickly

Tags: c#, class

```
class UserClass{

    #region Class properties which are binding from DB
    .
    .
    .
    #endregion


    #region Constructor Methods
    public UserClass(int _iUser_id)
    {
        // of course this is wrong but how can i quickly set properties 
        // which are coming from DB by extension method over context class?
        this = DAO.context.GetById<UserClass>(_iUser_id);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Does DAO.context.GetById<YetkiliKullanici>() return a UserClass object or something else?

Comment: Sorry, i changed the miss line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a static method instead of a constructor:

```
public static UserClass GetById(int userId) {
    return DAO.context.GetById<UserClass>(userId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is good, at least we have one way ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the properties manually.

If you really want to, you could use reflection or expression trees to loop through the properties, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Yes, it is very much code for this aim. Even it would be reusable.